# Typescript Prevent Unbound / Uncalled Methods in Conditionals Without Strict NULL Checks

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

For Angular / Typescript projects, I'm looking for a linting rule or similar means to prevent accidentally putting an unbound method in a conditional.

I'm looking for a linting rule / configuration that will work for projects using ES Lint, and with Typescript configured with `strictNullChecks: false`.

I would like for the following code to produce an error either at lint or compile time:

```js
export class Example {

  constructor() {
    if (this.isStillThe1900s) {
      // the above should be an error because:
      console.error("this will always be true because we forgot () on this.isStillThe1900s()");
    }
  }

  private isStillThe1900s(): boolean {
    return (new Date()).getFullYear() < 2000;
  }
  
}
```

I know Typescript added this check back in 3.7, however [according the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#uncalled-function-checks) this check requires strict null checking to be enabled.

I've also tried

- [@typescript-eslint/unbound-method](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/unbound-method/) TS/ES Lint rule
- [no-constant-condition](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-constant-condition) ES Lint rule
- [@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unnecessary-condition) TS/ES Lint rule doesn't seem usable on projects without stricNullChecks (as hinted at in the documentation), even when setting the linting flag `allowRuleToRunWithoutStrictNullChecksIKnowWhatIAmDoing: true`

Answer (score 0):

The [`allowRuleToRunWithoutStrictNullChecksIKnowWhatIAmDoing`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unnecessary-condition/#allowruletorunwithoutstrictnullchecksiknowwhatiamdoing) option in [`plugin:@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unnecessary-condition) does what you're looking for. It lets the lint rule run even with strict null checks off.

The option has a humorously inconveniently long name because it's dangerous. Per its docs:

> If for some reason you cannot turn on `strictNullChecks`, but still want to use this rule - you can use this option to allow it - but know that the behavior of this rule is undefined with the compiler option turned off. We will not accept bug reports if you are using this option.

...so the best case here is really to enable `strictNullChecks`. But if you *really* need then this dangerous rule option can do.

[Here's a typescript-eslint playground showing a lint report on your code](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.3.3&fileType=.ts&code=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FEQoLZhLBwDeAUHIhAHZoxQCuCM0AFAJSkWVwCWAZnFYwAFrzQA6cQGUYvJEgAqI4AEYAnAAZNaTuR48A9IbijiKAEYQAbsTQiIDJABM4F89TjAoUaG%2BAIKAxowABc3AYINGgQRBLevlCsAESi4nAA7vJIcChIGSgAnpjupozE7oHBxBnE-NAA5hDwHHA0pmKSMnIKympaOhzJ7ADcEXAAvtxT3GBQvNYoMMTd2X0a2mgcoW4QscAonvo8UMAwDFCerNTAGXAAIkvAHOwSDWcAYk5IAJoHSZwADxwABM2k0Y0oUymQA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6Jge1tiacTJTIAhtEK0yHJgBNK%2BSpPRgA2pETRoHaJAA0mcNhxD48DgHcASgkQAVDpaYB1WQAsOsfAGV8VMvgByCPAAws78ANbIAJIA0pymDs5C%2BJEAggC2ACIczADmit6wiPoQAL4AuvolICVAA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylAGYBDVCXTgwAXxCygA&tokens=false).

```
Unnecessary conditional, value is always truthy. 3:9 - 3:29
```